# OrderBy filter not working for kaltura media listing api using

Tags: node.js, kaltura

I am fetching media list from Kaltura which is working perfectly fine using Kaltura-client. But when trying to filter it using order by, it is not working as expected (Returning the same list).

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const kaltura = require('kaltura-client/KalturaClient');

exports.getMediaList = Promise.method((client, pager) => {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    return kaltura.services.media.listAction({ orderBy: 'CREATE_DATE_DESC'}, pager).execute(client).then((response) => {
      resolve(response.objects);
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, If we pass '**-createdAt**' for orderBy, We can get media in recent list

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const kaltura = require('kaltura-client/KalturaClient');

exports.getMediaList = Promise.method((client, pager) => {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    return kaltura.services.media.listAction({ orderBy: '-createdAt'}, pager).execute(client).then((response) => {
      resolve(response.objects);
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    })
  });
});
```